# Capitalize one word in a dynamic meta title

Tags: css, wordpress, title, meta, capitalize

Is there a way to  capitalize one word in a dynamic meta title?

Basically im using a slug in the meta title, but it is lowercase.  I would like to  capitalize just that one word, however im not sure the best way to do this?

```
<title><?php $taxonomy = 'propertytype'; $queried_term = get_query_var($taxonomy);$term = get_term_by( 'slug', $queried_term, $taxonomy ); echo $term->slug; ?> the rest of the thitle goes here</title>
```

Is there a method to  capitalize the slug in the title?

Many Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'propertytype';
$queried_term = get_query_var($taxonomy);
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', $queried_term, $taxonomy );
$cap = ucwords($term->slug);
?>
<title><?=$cap?>the rest of the thitle goes here</title>
```

Comment: That'd do it, but I'd say ucfirst() would be better, because it still gives the desired result even if the slug is more than one word.

Comment: he said to capitalize just one word so such I wrote

Comment: Well, ucwords() will capitalise every word in the string,while ucfirst() will only capitalise the first word.

Your method is correct, but if you made the small change of using ucfirst() it would make it more flexible.